# JavaFX and SwingNode - partial black Window

Tags: java, swing, javafx-8

I tried to use Swing Components in JavaFX with the SwingNode:

```
public class MyTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();

        Button btn = new Button("1");
        btn.setVisible(false);
        pane.getChildren().add(btn);

        createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode);
        pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);


        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 100, 50));

        stage.show();

        btn.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void createAndSetSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swingNode.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"));
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

After starting the application some parts of the window (the background and the JavaFX button) are black:

[image]

After a resize (or an other update) the window is shown correctly:

[image]

Why is it like this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your code looks pretty much identical to the [sample SwingNode code in Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html), so I don't know why it does not work for you.  My guess is that the issue is environment specific.  Maybe add details of your environment (Java version, OS version, Graphics Hardware, Graphics Driver), to your question.  Also you could file a report in the [JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/) with this information if you wish. FWIW, I use OS X 10.9 + Java 8u25 and nothing was black - all OK.

Comment: What version of the JDK is that?

Comment: The details to my environment:

Java SE 1.8 Development Kit 8 Update 31 (64bit)
under Windows 8.1 Pro

AMD Radeon HD 7800
Driver Version: 14.501.1003-141120a-178000C

Answer (score 3):

I've found an "awful" solution, but that works for me, repainting the Swing component in a delayed way, after showing the Stage:

```java
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            swingNode.getContent().repaint();
        }
    }, 500L);
```

so, your code will look like this:

```java
public class MyTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();

        Button btn = new Button("1");
        btn.setVisible(false);
        pane.getChildren().add(btn);

        createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode);
        pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);


        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 100, 50));

        stage.show();

        btn.setVisible(true);

        // delays Swing component repaint 1/2 sec.
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    swingNode.getContent().repaint();
                }
            }, 500L);

    }

    private void createAndSetSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swingNode.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"));
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

A bit late, but I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is an known bug in java 8 update 31.

(https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-37810)

It is fixed in java 8 update 40.

Comment: Currently with the JDK 11, the bug is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

objSwingNode.requestFocus();
            objSwingNode.autosize();