# Swing component showing as black in javafx

Tags: java, swing, debugging, graphics, javafx

I'm on a group project and we've been JavaFX almost exclusively, but our calendar is made of some JComponents(JTable), it's working as intended except when we run the code it is initially shown as a black box (pic #1) until the stage is resized or another action is performed. I looked at another question at stack overflow([JavaFX and SwingNode - partial black Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175904/javafx-and-swingnode-partial-black-window)) and there it is stated it was a known bug in update 31 and that it was fixed in update 40.

[image]

I'm running the code with JDK 1.8u45 and I'm more or less lost as to why this happens. Is this still a bug or is my code wrong?

Edit: Added the code I deleted from the test Application

```
package fxcalendartest;

import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class FxCalendarTest extends Application {

    Calendar c;

    DefaultTableModel model;
    int rYear, rWeek, rDay, curYear, curWeek, curDay;
    int q = 0;
    String[] monthname = {"Januar", "Februar", "Mars", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Desember"};

    GridPane calendarPane;
    HBox buttonBox;
    Button prevButton, nextButton, resetButton, activityButton, conferenceButton, entertainmentButton;
    SwingNode jTableNode;
    JTable table;
    String[] days;

    SimpleDateFormat df;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        buttonBox = new HBox(10);
        prevButton = new Button("Forrge Uke");
        nextButton = new Button("Neste Uke");
        activityButton = new Button("Aktiviteter");
        entertainmentButton = new Button("Underholdning");
        conferenceButton = new Button("Foredrag");
        resetButton = new Button("Tilbakestill");
        model = new DefaultTableModel() {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        model.setColumnCount(8);
        model.setRowCount(16);
        String[] weekdays = {"Klokkeslett", "Søn", "Man", "Tirs", "Ons", "Tors", "Fre", "Lør"};
        for (int i = 0; i < weekdays.length; i++) {
            model.setValueAt(weekdays[i], 0, i);
        }
        calendarPane = new GridPane();

        table = new JTable(model);

        days = new String[8];

        buttonBox.getChildren().addAll(prevButton, nextButton, resetButton, activityButton, entertainmentButton, conferenceButton);

        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        rWeek = c.get(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        rYear = c.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
        curWeek = rWeek;
        curYear = rYear;

        c.setTime(new Date());
        df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

        jTableNode = new SwingNode();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
          () -> {
              jTableNode.setContent(table);
          }
        );

        table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
        table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
        table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        table.setRowHeight(25);
        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        calendarPane.add(buttonBox, 0, 0, 8, 1);
        calendarPane.add(jTableNode, 0, 1, 8, 15);
        addCalendarDates(curWeek, curYear);

        Scene scene = new Scene(calendarPane, 660, 460);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public void addCalendarDates(int w, int y) {

        c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, w - 1);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
        model.setValueAt(monthname[c.get(Calendar.MONTH)], 0, 0);
        String[] timestamps = {"10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00"};
        for (int i = 0; i < timestamps.length; i++) {
            model.setValueAt(timestamps[i], i + 2, 0);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < days.length; i++) {
            int row = 1;
            int column = i;
            Date date = c.getTime();
            model.setValueAt(df.format(date), row, column);
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            days[i] = df.format(date);
        }//end of for
        table.setDefaultRenderer(table.getColumnClass(0), new DefaultTableCellRenderer());
    }//end of class

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

Comment: Could you add a more complete example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think to manage the threading correctly, you should create the table and configure it on the AWT thread: i.e. move `table = new JTable(...)` and all the `table.xxx(...)` calls into the `invokeLater(...)` runnable. I don't know if this will fix the issue though (I sort of suspect not). As mentioned, if you create an MCVE it will be easier for others to help.

Comment: I put all the table related stuff into the invokeLater, more or less fixed the problem. When I implemented the code into our program it works sort of. It dissapears sometimes, but comes back whenever something is clicked.