# JavaFx SwingNode - Displays Black, Background, or Component Randomly

Tags: java, swing, debugging, javafx

I am having a problem with JavaFx's SwingNode showing the components it holds in Java 1.8.0_102-b14. I am not sure if this issue is due to my Java version being old, a bug within the current (if mine is current) Java release, or some SwingNode process I am doing incorrectly. I know this issue has been reported before [JavaFX and SwingNode - partial black Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175904/javafx-and-swingnode-partial-black-window) so I am really looking for feedback on my Java version.

This code will usually display "button1" wrong, as in black or the background color, until the mouse hovers over it or it is clicked. This is not an ideal workaround for me as my project using much more complex swing panels in the Fx project and pure Fx is not an option unfortunately.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Test extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
      final SwingNode swingNode1 = new SwingNode();
      final SwingNode swingNode2 = new SwingNode();

      swingNode2.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"+2));
      swingNode1.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"+1));

      BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
      pane.setLeft(swingNode1);
      pane.setRight(swingNode2);

      stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 200, 50));
      stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }
}
```

In creating this sssce I found that setting the content in the left SwingNode before setting the content in the right SwingNode corrected the issue for this simple code, but not for my larger project. So I am guessing it is a memory leak, but I can't tell from my machine.

Can someone test this code and see if they get similar results?

Edit: Thanks for the quick feedback, please don't focus on the buttons as they are merely a tool to demonstrate my problem. The weird functionality acts in the same way with other objects rather than buttons.

Comment: Even copying the Javadocs example per @James_D the issue still persists. Are there any other ideas? This bug was apparently fixed in U40, could it have been broken again?

Comment: I still see this issue in the latest 8u121 on Windows 7, using either invokeLater() or invokeAndWait()

Comment: Apparently it is stil present in 2023 with gluon openjfx and openjdk 17

Answer (score 3):

You *must* create and display Swing components on the AWT Event Dispatch thread (see [Swing's threading policy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading)). The `Application.start()` method is [invoked on the FX Application Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#start-javafx.stage.Stage-).

Thus you need

```
public class Test extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
      final SwingNode swingNode1 = new SwingNode();
      final SwingNode swingNode2 = new SwingNode();

      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
          swingNode2.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"+2));
          swingNode1.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"+1));
      });

      BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
      pane.setLeft(swingNode1);
      pane.setRight(swingNode2);

      stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 200, 50));
      stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Using this method, the button appears black once again. However I should not that on clicking off the window, the button becomes visible. Clicking on the other button also makes it visible. While not perfect, I think this could work.

Answer (score 2):

When using a JTextArea in a SwingNode (using JDK 1.8.0_202) I saw this rendering issue again. The issue, for me, happened in two cases:

**On every window resize attempt:** To remedy this I added a listener to set the content of the swing node on each resize of the window.

**On SplitPane divider position update:** Since the swingNode was in a SplitPane I added the listener to that as well.

Those two updates seemed to do the trick except if I moved the divider too fast the black background would come back again. To fix this I changed the cache on the SwingNode to true and the cacheHint to `CacheHint.SPEED`. This removed all rendering issues, but it still has one side effect that since the textArea is being cached and displayed as a bitmap it will not respond to user interaction for a small period of time. This worked for my case because my textarea was not editable.

Note that use of SwingUtilities.invokelater didn't seem to have any effect on the rendering so I left it out of this code.

```
swingNode.setContent(textArea);

ChangeListener<Number> sizeListener = (o, oldSize, newSize) -> {
  swingNode.setContent(textArea);
};

splitPane.getDividers().forEach( divider -> divider.positionProperty().addListener(sizeListener));
primaryStage.heightProperty().addListener(sizeListener);
primaryStage.widthProperty().addListener(sizeListener);

swingNode.setCache(true);
swingNode.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED);
```

This issue seems to be fixed for JButton.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed this behaviour by repainting the Swing component in a delayed way, after showing the Stage:

```java
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            swingNode1.getContent().repaint();
            swingNode2.getContent().repaint();
        }
    }, 100L);
```

so, your code will look like this:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Test extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
      final SwingNode swingNode1 = new SwingNode();
      final SwingNode swingNode2 = new SwingNode();

      swingNode2.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"+2));
      swingNode1.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"+1));

      BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
      pane.setLeft(swingNode1);
      pane.setRight(swingNode2);

      stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 200, 50));
      stage.show();

      new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
           public void run() {
                swingNode1.getContent().repaint();
                swingNode2.getContent().repaint();
           }
       }, 100L);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }
}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

There was a [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8097328) concerning this and similar issues that was supposedly resolved, but apparently it wasn't completely fixed, since I'm still seeing black squares instead of buttons on startup (1.8.0_91-b15).

This is happening because your JavaFX components are being created before your Swing components. You can fix this behavior either by invoking `requestFocus()` on each of the components to ensure that they get rendered properly:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    swingNode1.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"+1));
    swingNode1.requestFocus();
    swingNode2.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"+2));
    swingNode2.requestFocus();
});
```

Or by using `invokeAndWait()`, so that your application waits until the creation of your Swing components has finished.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
    swingNode1.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"+1));
    swingNode2.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"+2));
});
```

Also, as James_D mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39004824/2440202), don't forget that you have create Swing components on EDT.